# Why isn't mysql python flask website working on heroku?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, heroku

So I've uploaded my website onto heroku. I'm using python flask with a mysql database. It works fine on my local computer. But on heroku it is giving me this error message :

```
PS C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial> heroku logs
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.56.0.
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536729+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536729+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536737+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536737+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536738+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536738+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536739+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/routes.py", line 27, in index
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536740+00:00 app[web.1]: return render_template('index.html', title='Home')
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 136, in render_template
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536741+00:00 app[web.1]: ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536741+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 838, in update_template_context
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536742+00:00 app[web.1]: context.update(func())
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536742+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 379, in _user_context_processor
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536743+00:00 app[web.1]: return dict(current_user=_get_user())
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536743+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 346, in _get_user
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536743+00:00 app[web.1]: current_app.login_manager._load_user()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536744+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 318, in _load_user
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536744+00:00 app[web.1]: user = self._user_callback(user_id)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536745+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/models.py", line 57, in load_user
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536745+00:00 app[web.1]: return User2.query.get(int(id))
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536745+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1018, in get
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536746+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_pk_identity)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536746+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1135, in _get_impl
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536747+00:00 app[web.1]: return db_load_fn(self, primary_key_identity)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536747+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 286, in load_on_pk_identity
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536747+00:00 app[web.1]: return q.one()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536748+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3490, in one
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536748+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = self.one_or_none()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536749+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3459, in one_or_none
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536749+00:00 app[web.1]: ret = list(self)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536749+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536750+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536750+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3556, in _execute_and_instances
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536751+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = self._get_bind_args(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3571, in _get_bind_args
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536751+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3550, in _connection_from_session
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536752+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536752+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1142, in
connection
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536753+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._connection_for_bind(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536753+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1150, in
_connection_for_bind
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536754+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536754+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 433, in _connection_for_bind
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536754+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = bind._contextual_connect()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536755+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2302, in
_contextual_connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536755+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536756+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2339, in
_wrap_pool_connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536756+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536758+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1583, in
_handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536758+00:00 app[web.1]: util.raise_(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536758+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536759+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536759+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2336, in
_wrap_pool_connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536759+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536760+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 364, in connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536760+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536765+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 778, in _checkout
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536766+00:00 app[web.1]: fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536766+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 495, in checkout
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536767+00:00 app[web.1]: rec = pool._do_get()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536767+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536767+00:00 app[web.1]: self._dec_overflow()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68,
in __exit__
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536768+00:00 app[web.1]: compat.raise_(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536768+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536769+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536769+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536770+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._create_connection()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536770+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536770+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536771+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 440, in __init__
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536771+00:00 app[web.1]: self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536772+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536772+00:00 app[web.1]: pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536773+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68,
in __exit__
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536773+00:00 app[web.1]: compat.raise_(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536774+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536774+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 656, in __connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536775+00:00 app[web.1]: connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536775+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536776+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536776+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 508, in connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536776+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536777+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536777+00:00 app[web.1]: return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536777+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536778+00:00 app[web.1]: self.connect(**kwargs)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536778+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536779+00:00 app[web.1]: self._open_connection()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536779+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206,
in _open_connection
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536780+00:00 app[web.1]: self._socket.open_connection()
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536780+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in
open_connection
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536780+00:00 app[web.1]: raise errors.InterfaceError(
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536782+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.536782+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)
2021-07-08T13:20:35.538388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=iptutorial2.herokuapp.com request_id=986999dc-cd77-46e0-88fd-83de35567e36 fwd="86.190.136.60" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=431ms status=500 bytes=477 protocol=https
2021-07-08T13:20:35.543924+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.27.229 - - [08/Jul/2021:13:20:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
```

So what does this mean?? And what can I do about it? How can I fix it?? I was using a mysql lite database before and uploaded it onto heroku and it was working but now I've changed it to a mysql database and it's not working anymore.

Comment: You can't connect to your mysql hosted on local machine, you need to host it on hosting platform or use the postures add on of heroku with your application. You can follow this article  to do so, https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-a-micro-flask-application-into-heroku-with-postgresql-database-d95fd0c19408

Comment: How do you expect there to be a database running locally on the dyno (localhost:3306)? Typically you'd configure the connection with an environment variable.

Comment: Sometimes you have to change your Heroku MySQL database credentials appropriate to your project . Here error shows `localhost` db url . Also the ports . Also refer this document [How to deploy Python Flask MySQL based application in Heroku Cloud](https://roytuts.com/how-to-deploy-python-flask-mysql-based-application-in-heroku-cloud/)